# Is the SE/Combined flair somehow broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

For a couple of days now, I cannot see my combined flair. I just have a regular hyperlink where the image should be (i.e., the image fails to load).

I *do* meet the minimum requirements: I have 3 accounts that are over the 200 rep limit, and it was working just fine at least a week ago.

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduced it, everyone's combine flair is now redirects to 500 internal server error page.

Comment: Me too, I randomly dropped by by my homepage and saw that the flair was broken. I thought it would be temporary disturbance, though.

Comment: I can sense a great disturbance in the flair!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a disturbance in the force (read: file permissions) and flair was caught in the galactic cross-fire.  Evil has been destroyed, all is well, the droids you're looking for can again be found:

[image: User Flair]

[Link](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/c6192ba0-f584-4bb2-95a5-67615545ac8b.png)

Comment: Same bug re-appeared

Comment: It was fixed for 2 days and then it re-appeared again