# My stack exchange flair is down

Tags: support, status-completed, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the SE/Combined flair somehow broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90639/is-the-se-combined-flair-somehow-broken)

My stack exchange flair is down. Its only the combined one, individual ones are still working.

I checked Jeff's at [codinghorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) and his is down as well.

Its been like this for a couple hours.

Thought I would bring it to someones attention.

Comment: I noticed this earlier, too, but mine seems to be back. And so does Jeff's.

Comment: @Renesis maybe were seeing different servers or something because I just checked Jeff's on a new browser and its still down. Its not a huge deal, just thought I would let someone know.

Comment: you're correct...one of the servers didn't get a permissions change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already fixed. see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90639/is-the-se-combined-flair-somehow-broken)

[image]

[image]

Note: I can see above on mine as like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMpYI.png) or as David said one of the server still have broken code.

Comment: Could you please tell me, where I can find the link again? The "got flair?" link is not visible to me...

Comment: @WarrenFaith, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138437/warrenfaith?tab=flair ?

Comment: hmpf... I didn't know it was moved as I only find the "below gravatar" answers here... thanks!