# Combined flair bug re-appeared

Tags: bug, flair, combined-flair

This bug re-appeared [Is the SE/Combined flair somehow broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90639/is-the-se-combined-flair-somehow-broken/90690#90690)

I don't know how to bring back attention to this topic without asking a duplicate question, apparently commenting on the answer of the topic doesnt give the answerer/ mod a notification

Apparently the bug being back can be seen in the same answer of that old topic when the mentioned image in the answer doesnt load.

Comment: A comment to an answer always notifies the owner of that answer.

Comment: @Luuklag, if you [check their last seen time](https://stackexchange.com/users/7598/nick-craver?tab=accounts) you can see that Nick has been online and didn't respond to the 20 hour old comment. Also, that bug report is 10 years old; it's not unreasonable to file a new report.

Comment: @Rob, there has been a more recent report, let me see if I can find that.